# Python Combine multiple data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to combine spreadsheets with a common column name (server/instance) however each spreadsheet doesn't have the same number of rows for the common field. Below I outlined the two data frames. I am trying to figure out if this can be output back to to an excel file or use some type of module to create a python GUI.

Data File 1

```
sever   database    still running
---------------------------------    
test    database1   TRUE
test    database2   TRUE
test2   database1   FALSE
test2   database3   TRUE
```

Data File 2 (instance is the same as server from DF1)

```
Instance app name contact
-------------------------
test     app1     harry
test     app2     sally
test     app3     sally
test2    app1     sally
```

Final output

```
server  database    still running   app name    contact
-------------------------------------------------------
test    database1   TRUE            app1        harry
test    database2   TRUE            app2        sally
test                                app3        sally
test2   database1   FALSE           app1        sally
test2   database3   TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand your logic of merging these spreadsheets, but probably `merge` from `pandas` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) may be useful. So, firstly you can read these spreadsheets using `pandas.read_csv()`, then perform `merge` and in the end save resulting `dataframe` using `pandas.to_csv()`.